# javascript script innerhtml

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

hi i want to call function changeDivHTML which pass the image

```
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeDivHTML(<img src='.DIR_WS_IMAGES .$addimages_images[$item]['popimage'].'>)">
```

and the function add this images to particular id's div.

function is this

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function changeDivHTML(item)
                    {
                    alert(item);
                        previousInnerHTML = 'item';
                        alert(previousInnerHTML);
                        document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previousInnerHTML;
                     }
</script>
```

but when i click on images browser showas the javascript error.

```
Error: invalid XML attribute value
Source File: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxx/product_info.php?products_id=31
Line: 1, Column: 23
Source Code:
changeDivHTML(<img src=images/products/top/product_big1.jpg>)
```

plsease help how to remove this error.

Answer (score 2):

`changeDivHTML` requires that you pass a string to it, but you forgot the delimiters which is what's causing the errors.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeDivHTML('<img src=\''.DIR_WS_IMAGES .$addimages_images[$item]['popimage'].'\'>')">
```

Answer (score 2):

First you must pass  as a string, not as tag! And, you must close it at the end.

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeDivHTML(\"<img src='.DIR_WS_IMAGES .$addimages_images[$item]['popimage'].'/>\")">`

Second, you should change script like this, so you get the image tag where you want:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
                    function changeDivHTML(item)
                    {                        
                        previousInnerHTML = item;
                        document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = previousInnerHTML;
                     }
</script>
```

Hope I helped. =)

Comment: Actually, your first example will not work because HTML attributes do not have an escape character.  For instance, you cannot have `onclick="str = \"I'm a string\""`, because HTML parsers will end the attribute at the first `\"`, regardless of the escape character.

Answer (score 1):

Try is by passing the parameter as string, as below

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeDivHTML('<img src='.DIR_WS_IMAGES .$addimages_images[$item]['popimage'].'>')">
```

Don't forget to handle escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

Pass it a string (i.e. something surrounded by quote marks), rather then some invalid [E4X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/E4X)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you're trying to change the inner HTML of a DIV to some other content when clicking a link is pressed.  It's easier to refer to some other HTML already in the document (possibly concealed by `style="display:none"` if it must be hidden initially).  Here's an example:

```
<div id="div1">Here's div1 <img src="1.png"/></div>
<div id="div2">Here's div2.</div>
<a href="#" onclick="changeDivHtml('div1', 'div2')">Click to Change</a>
<script language="javascript">
  function changeDivHtml(source, target) {
    var elSource = document.getElementById(source)
      , elTarget = document.getElementById(target);
    elTarget.innerHTML = elSource.innerHTML;
  }
</script>
```